# Quartz job not working with reduced thread number

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I want to configure the number of threads that are assigned to the Quartz scheduler job which is calling the Spring Data method.

Configuration class looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public JobDetail verificationTokenRemoverJobDetails() {
    return
        JobBuilder
            .newJob(VerificationTokenQuartzRemoverJob.class)
            .withIdentity("Job for verification token remover")
            .storeDurably()
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Trigger verificationTokenRemoverJobTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail) {
    return
        TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .forJob(jobDetail)
            .withIdentity("Trigger for verification token remover")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/2 * * ? * * *"))
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    Properties quartzProperties = new Properties();
    quartzProperties.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "1");
    quartzProperties.put("spring.quartz.job-store-type", "jdbc");
    quartzProperties.put("spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered", "true");
    quartzProperties.put("spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId", "AUTO");
    scheduler.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties);
    return scheduler;
  }
}
```

My job class looks like:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class VerificationTokenQuartzRemoverJob implements Job {

  private VerificationTokenRepository verificationTokenRepository;
  private QuartzProperties quartzProperties;

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
    verificationTokenRepository.deleteAllByCreatedLessThan(
        now().minusMinutes(parseLong(quartzProperties.getVerificationTokensOlderThan())));
  }
}
```

Problem is that I decided to reduce the number of threads which are used while job execution because default number `10` is too much from my point of view. I added bean `public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean()` which reduced the number of threads with half-way victory result like:

```
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Seemingly this should work but despite the CRON expression(every two seconds), the job is not starting at all and the application is idling. If I will comment out third configuration bean job works again with an information in IntelliJ run window but with 10 threads what is not desirable.

All I want to achieve is configure my Quartz Job to work on a specified number of threads. Moreover, I want to know how to configure properly Quartz mechanism because as far as I understand my

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean()
```

will lead to permit single thread for each Quartz job so in case that in future I will have more than one job that can lead to the collision, isn't it? I will be grateful for suggestions on how to reach a goal and configure Quartz.

Comment: Doesn't that last log message indicate that the pool is misconfigured? The implementation doesn't support persistence or clustering, which you try to turn on. How are you confirming that it's working? Records written to db?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, a recent version of Spring Boot supports quartz out-of-the-box. By specifing the properties in your `application.properties`. If you don't want that remove the `spring.quartz.properties.` from your  current properties as else it won't work. However I would strongly suggest using the Spring Boot configured one, instead of trying it yourself.